# Android: About custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I made custom ListView in xml

If I do not use the CheckBox, then an item in the list can be selected for the context menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            ... />
        <TextView
            ... />
        <TextView
            ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But if I add CheckBox, then the active area is only CheckBox,I can not call context menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
            <TextView
                ... />
            <TextView
                ... />
            <TextView
                ... />
            <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="CheckBox"
         />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Part of my Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_spmmain);


  schedule_listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MainActivity_schedule);

  registerForContextMenu(schedule_listview);
}

@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.spmmain_context, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.MainActivity_contextmenu_edit){
            startAddActionActivity();
        }
        else if(item.getItemId() == R.id.MainActivity_contextmenu_delete){

        }


        return true;
    }
```

How I can activate ListWidget item for using context menu with CheckBox?

PS Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CheckBox` is taking the focus which will prevent other click events. Add the [focusable attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3afocusable) and set it to false.

`android:focusable="false"`

This allows the `ListView` item to also fire events.

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="CheckBox"
    android:focusable="false"
     />
```